# Best way to wake 0-N sleeping goroutines at once

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm writing a program where I start N (N is a command-line argument) worker threads, and at any time 0 to N-1 of them can be waiting on another to update a variable. What's the best way for the threads to wait for this event, and the best way for one of the threads to notify all the others at once of the event occurring? This event will be sent multiple times by each thread.
`sync.Cond` isn't appropriate because the threads don't need to lock a resource upon waking from sleep. `sync.WaitGroup` won't work because I don't know how many times to call `wg.Done()`.

Solution #1: I *could* use a `sync.Mutex` and have the thread that will eventually notify the others acquire the lock and then unlock it to notify the others, but it seems really inefficient for the others to all fight over a lock when they all just need to pop out of sleep, read a variable to see if that particular worker is now the master, and then either go back to sleep or start working.

Solution #2: Create a wrapper for `sync.WaitGroup` that allows keeping track of the number of waiting threads so that I can call `wg.Add(-numWaitingThreads)` to wake them. This sounds like a headache to figure out how to code it without all sorts of race conditions.

Solution #3: Until someone comes up with a better idea, I'll be using a list of N channels and have the notifier non-blocking-send to all of the channels except its own. Is this really the best way?

More details: I give each worker some unique credits and have a central variable for "which credit is the next to be written to the output file". When a worker finishes its work for whichever credit ID it was working on, it needs to do the following:

```
for centralNextCreditID != creditID {
  wait_for_centralNextCreditID_to_change()
}
saveWorkToFile()
centralNextCreditID++
wake_other_threads_waiting_for_centralNextCreditID_to_change()
```

Comment: If you have enough waiting goroutines to make a difference, you probably need to benchmark anyway to see which approach works best with your workload and the current implementation.

Comment: You can have one shared channel where N-1 goroutines are waiting to read, and then the N'th goroutine wants to release them, it can close the channel.

Comment: @BurakSerdar That's a really interesting approach. How would you reset that to allow for the event to fire again later? `close(ch); ch = make(chan bool)`?

Comment: You have to show some code to figure that out.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I edited my question to provide some details at the end. I was hoping for a more general way of sending notifications, but I ended up going with sync.Cond as shown in the accepted answer, since it seems like better practice for this case than a general way of sending and waiting on notifications. If there's a general way to do notifications in Go, I'd still like to know it, but I suspect it doesn't exist because it's a bad idea for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it does seem like this is an appropriate use case for `sync.Cond`. You can use a `*RWMutex.RLocker()` for `Cond.L` so all goroutines can acquire the read lock simultaneously once the `Cond.Broadcast()` is sent.

Additionally, it may be worth making sure you hold a write lock when changing this "who's master" variable to avoid race conditions, which would make `sync.Cond` an even better fit.

Comment: It took a lot of `fatal error: sync: RUnlock of unlocked RWMutex` messages before I figured out that you have to follow the code snippet from the documentation to the letter for sync.Cond to work:
`c.L.Lock();
for !condition() {
    c.Wait()
}
... make use of condition ... ;
c.L.Unlock()`
In my case, `make use of condition` was nothing and I instead did some work, write-locked the variable, and then changed the variable, did `cond.Broadcast()`, and finally released the write lock.

Answer (score 1):

> sync.WaitGroup won't work because I don't know how many times to call wg.Done().

wg can be used in this case. Make a `wg` with count 1 and pass this to the N goroutines. Make them `wg.Wait()`, except the one that updates the variable.
The goroutine updating the variable calls `wg.Done()` after successful update thus resulting in N goroutines to come out of wait and start executing further.

Comment: Good suggestion, I had to clarify my question because of this. Unfortunately, this doesn't work because when you do `wg.Done(); wg.Add(1)` to send the event and then reset it for another event to send it later, a thread panics with the message `panic: sync: WaitGroup is reused before previous Wait has returned`.

Answer (score 0):

The title says that you want to wake 0-N sleeping goroutines, but the body of the question indicates that you only need to wake the goroutine for the next id (if there is a goroutine waiting).

Here's how to implement the problem described in the body of the question:

```
// waiter sequences work according to an incrementing id.
type waiter struct {
    mu      sync.Mutex
    id      int
    waiting map[int]chan struct{}
}

func NewWaiter(firstID int) *waiter {
    return &waiter{id: firstID, waiting: make(map[int]chan struct{})}
}

// wait waits for id's turn in the sequence.
func (w *waiter) wait(id int) {
    w.mu.Lock()
    if w.id == id {
        // This id is next. Nothing to do.
        w.mu.Unlock()
        return
    }
    // Wait for our turn.
    c := make(chan struct{})
    w.waiting[id] = c
    w.mu.Unlock()
    <-c
}

// done signals that the work for the previous id is done.
func (w *waiter) done() {
    w.mu.Lock()
    w.id++
    c, ok := w.waiting[w.id]
    if ok {
        delete(w.waiting, w.id)
    }
    w.mu.Unlock()
    if ok {
        // close cause c to receive a zero value
        close(c)
    }
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
for _, creditID := range creditIDs {
    doWorkFor(creditID)
    waiter.wait(creditID)
    saveWorkToFile()
    waiter.done()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`WaitGroup` is the best option. The reason is that is keeps its *signalled* state and you are safe from deadlock if the main thread signals too early.

If you use `Cond` there is a risk that the main thread calls `cond.Broadcast` **BEFORE** the worker thread calls `cond.Wait()`. Since `Cond` doesn't remember that it was signalled, the worker thread will wait for the event to happen.
Here is an example: https://go.dev/play/p/YLfvEGO2A18
The main thread broadcasts too early, the worker threads run into a deadlock.

Same case with `con.WaitGroup`: https://go.dev/play/p/R6_-ULo2eJ2
The main thread releases the wait group too early, but there is no deadlock.

Comment: Correct use of `Cond` should not result in deadlock, as the lock must be held while changing the condition, and the condition should be observed under lock before calling `Wait`.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I dare guess, you didn't run the example with `Cond`? Try https://go.dev/play/p/YLfvEGO2A18 and enjoy the panic message `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

Comment: My comment was not about the example, but just about `Cond` itself. Correct use of `Cond` should not result in deadlock. The link you gave is not correct use of `Cond` because there is no **condition**. `Cond` itself is not the condition, it is only a synchronization tool that controls *access* to the condition. Importantly, a goroutine should only `Wait` when it has observed *under lock* that the condition is in such a state that necessitates waiting.